# X-Slidebox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mozilla

I am trying to use http://mozilla.github.io/brick/demos/slidebox/index.html and following is my code. Ther slide one is loading fine but when ever i click on next button it gives following error. Kindly help!!!

`ReferenceError: slidebox is not defined`

I am confused what I did wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-US" class="csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions" slick-uniqueid="3">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/brick-1.0beta8.byob.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/brick-1.0beta8.byob.min.js"></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function() { 

// go back a slide
prevButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   slidebox.slidePrevious(); 
});

// go forward a slide
nextButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   slidebox.slideNext(); 
});

// jump to slide 6
slideToButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   slidebox.slideTo(6); 
});

 });

</script>

<head>
<body>
<x-slidebox orientation="x">
    <x-slides>
        <x-slide>Slide 0</x-slide>
        <x-slide selected>Slide 1
        </x-slide>
        <x-slide>Slide 2</x-slide>
        <x-slide>Slide 3</x-slide>
        <x-slide>Slide 4</x-slide>
        <x-slide>Slide 5</x-slide>
        <x-slide>Slide 6</x-slide>
    </x-slides>
</x-slidebox>

<button id="nextButton" class="btn btn-default nextButton">Next</button>
<button id="slideToButton" class="btn btn-default slideToButton">Pre</button>

<button id="prevButton" class="btn btn-default prevButton">Pre</button>
<button onclick="ab();" id="pre" class="pre">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query for the slidebox first.  Add this before you attach the event listeners.

```
var slidebox = $('x-slidebox')[0];
```

You also need to query for the buttons before using them.

```
$('nextButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
   slidebox.slideNext(); 
});
```

Here's the complete js code that *should* work.

https://gist.github.com/pennyfx/6896373

As I mentioned above, the part that you are missing is where you have to select the slidebox and button elements from the DOM before using them.   I'm assuming that authors of Brick thought that part is obvious and left it off their tutorials.

Comment: After applying your suggested modification, now i am getting this error `TypeError: slidebox.slideNext is not a function`

Comment: Is the slidebox included in your Brick package?    Is xtag.tags['x-slidebox'] defined ?

Comment: yes I only download the bundle of slidebox only and my slides are enclosing altogether but I am not able to apply any action on them, Like Next Slide Etc, My complete code is above in my question. Can you please take a look into it and let me know what I did wrong http://mozilla.github.io/brick/demos/slidebox/index.html

Comment: I know they want us to avoid say thanks. But I reall want to thank you for your time :)